# Install ubuntu 14.04 and windows 8 in different hard drives

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, hard-drive

I use Ubuntu 14.04 as my operating system and recently I bought a new hard drive where I want to install windows 8.

How I can install 8 in the second hard drive and then be able to boot them from the *Ubuntu grub*?

Comment: Is this newer hardware with UEFI. And then did you install Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS mode. While both installs if on different drives do not have to be same boot mode, you can only boot from grub if installs are both UEFI or both BIOS. Windows may install boot partition to drive set as default boot in BIOS/UEFI. So best to totally disconnect Ubuntu drive and install Windows. Then each install is stand-alone. And a `sudo update-grub` after connecting Ubuntu should find the Windows install if in same boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Insert the second hdd.

Check it is /dev/sdb and Ubuntu hdd is /dev/sda.

If not so, change the ide/sata wires.

Disconnect Ubuntu hdd.

Install Windows.

Connect Ubuntu hdd.

Boot Ubuntu.

Open a terminal.

And run:

```
sudo -i
update-grub
```

Windows should enter the Grub menu.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, put the new hard drive as the first hard drive (through BIOS or physical swap) and install it that way and leave it that way.  Microsoft OSes have to be installed on the first primary partition of the first hard drive since MS-DOS 2.11 (never used any version prior to that).
*that's what you get when you have a monopoly!*

Answer (score -1):

Firstly setup the Win8 to a free-space on your HDD.
Then Use a Live any Linux CD/DVD/USB for the Boot Menu.
You need to install GRUB. 
You'll se if you put your Live CD to your computer.

Comment: Windows cannot be installed on the second hard drive of a system, so your procedure would not work...  Please delete your answer to revert the negative reputation points.